# monitoring the lifecyle of an akka stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want to monitor the lifecyle of an akka-stream, it seems like [monitor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#monitor) would do what I need, but my monitoring function is async, returning a `Future`, so I would need monitor to be async as well.

`monitor` has the following signature:

```
def monitor[Mat2]()(combine: (Mat, FlowMonitor[Out]) ⇒ Mat2): ReprMat[Out, Mat2]
```

But I would need something like:

```
def monitorAsync[Mat2]()(combine: (Mat, FlowMonitor[Out]) ⇒ Future[Mat2]): ReprMat[Out, Mat2]
```

Is there a way to implement this using akka-streams primitives like `mapAsync`.

I suppose I could use `mapAsync` + `watchTermination` but seems like a complicated solution when `monitor` almost does what I need.

Comment: We have an open ticket for "flat-mapping" future materialized values that you can follow here: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/23303

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `monitor` was not what I wanted at all, as a would only have access to `FlowMonitor` after the materialization of the stream.

I ended up implementing this with `mapAsync` and `recover`. I am simplifying here, but something like this:

```
val monitor = new Monitor {
  def onNext: Future[Unit] = ???
  def onFailure(cause: Throwable): Future[Unit] = ???
  def onFinish: Future[Unit] = ???
}

source.mapAsync { v => 
  monitor.onNext.map(_ => v)
}.watchTermination() { (mat, doneF) =>
  doneF.flatMap(_ => monitor.onFinish).recoverWith( case ex => monitor.onFailure(ex))
}
```